# Update SQL database via MS Access with an identical value gives a lock violation

Tags: mysql, ms-access

EDIT:  I've done a terrible job of explaining this.  The short version:

> If I try to update a table value in a MySQL table from MS Access with an identical value, I get a lock violation. Table1.Value1 contains "some_value". I update Table1.Value1 with "some_value" I get a lock error. Any other value works fine. I can also make the update in MySQL directly without issue. The error is only there when done from MS Access.

I have a mySQL database where I need to update 2 fields in different tables from MS Access.  It is for the cancellation of a product.

The 2 fields are account.status and product.date

When a customer cancels an account, account.status should change to "Cancelled" and a date should pop up in product.date, the date is taken from account.date, and 30 days are added.

This works fine as long as account.status IS NOT "Cancelled" already.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to have MS Access ignore the lock violation I get then.

If account.status is anything but "Cancelled" it works just fine, but when updating the table with an identical value I get a lock violation.

```
UPDATE product INNER JOIN account ON product.cust_id = account.id SET product.date = [account].[date]+30, account.status = "Cancelled" WHERE (((account.id)=[Forms]![donotrenew kilde]![id]));
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'identical value' - what is identical? Why would product.date be dependent on account.date? I've never seen a product table directly related to customer. Customarily associated with OrderDetails table.

Comment: In the case where account.status is "Cancelled" when I try to update it to "Cancelled", I get a lock violation in MS Access, running just the SQL directly against the database in PhpMyAdmin works fine.  The dates are not the issue here, I'm just explaining.  Product.date is acutally a deletion date.  So 30 days after the account has expired, the product is set for termination.

Comment: Don't think I've never seen a query that attempted to update two tables in one action. The join has to result in an editable query. You say it works in another interface so it should in Access. Since I don't have similar data structure can't really test and analyze. Perhaps edit question to show sample data - as text, not image.

Comment: It's hard to show examples without revealing some table and column names that cannot be out there.  

The above code works 100% fine if the account.status is "Active" or any other status besides "Cancelled".  The only other real relevant post I've found is this:  http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/update-query-errors-with-lock-violation-how-to-troubleshoot-58397.html  

They did not post a real solution.  But it seems this is behavior of updating MySQL from MS Access.

Comment: Likewise, I am get the same lock violation if I try to update account.status from "Active to "Active".  Updating from "Active" to "Cancelled" works fine.  The error is only there when updating to the same value as is allready in the table.

Comment: Why would table and column names be proprietary? Is this 1-to-many relationship? I just did a test and no problem with Access to Access (not split db). Sorry, I do not have MySQL Can't replicate issue so can't advise solution.

Comment: It's not the table names.  I'm sorry, I feel I've done a bad job at explaining this.  The short of it is, if I try to update a table value in a MySQL table from MS Access with an identical value, I get a lock violation.  Table1.Value1 contains "value1".  I update Table1.Value1 with "value1" I get a lock error.  Any other value works fine.  I can also make the update in MySQL directly.  The error is only there when done from MS Access.

Comment: Well, I still can't help because I cannot replicate issue. So unless someone else jumps in, you are on your own.

Comment: Tables got primary key and timestamps? ODBC Option 2 is active (return matching rows). Got familiar with the MySQL Connector/ODBC-Doks?